# I can't setup socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I decided to use socket.io, to send data from serverside to client side, but it is giving me this error :

```
VM134:3511 GET http://[url]/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LS52PFM 404 (Not Found)
```

and :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

And here is my app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var facebook = require('./routes/facebook');
var dev = require('./routes/dev');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var ux = require('./routes/ux');
var session = require('express-session');
//Maziar added
var addPlaces = require('./routes/addPlaces');


// socket.io stuff : 
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

index.js :

```
// io socket{
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);



//io socket end. }
function emit() { io.sockets.emit('reload'); };

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And my client side code :

```
var socket = io();
socket.on("reload", function(r) { alert('love you!'); });
```

And in the html part I have added in the head :

```
<script src="scripts/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

( I have also downloaded the socket.io.js file locally just to make sure it can access it! )

Package.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "chance": "^1.0.3",
    "connect-ensure-login": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "hjs": "~0.0.6",
    "mongodb": "^2.1.19",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "util": "^0.10.3",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0"
  }
```

Temp build :

```
 /tmp/build_39cf5617a994685d99e4b2a55679a42b
remote:        ├── chance@1.0.4
remote:        ├── connect-ensure-login@0.1.1
remote:        ├─┬ express-session@1.14.1
remote:        │ ├── cookie@0.3.1
remote:        │ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
remote:        │ ├── crc@3.4.0
remote:        │ ├── depd@1.1.0
remote:        │ ├── on-headers@1.0.1
remote:        │ ├── parseurl@1.3.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ uid-safe@2.1.2
remote:        │ │ ├── base64-url@1.3.2
remote:        │ │ └── random-bytes@1.0.0
remote:        │ └── utils-merge@1.0.0
remote:        ├─┬ mongodb@2.2.9
remote:        │ ├── es6-promise@3.2.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ mongodb-core@2.0.11
remote:        │ │ ├── bson@0.5.4
remote:        │ │ └─┬ require_optional@1.0.0
remote:        │ │   ├── resolve-from@2.0.0
remote:        │ │   └── semver@5.3.0
remote:        │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.1.5
remote:        │   ├── buffer-shims@1.0.0
remote:        │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
remote:        │   ├── inherits@2.0.3
remote:        │   ├── isarray@1.0.0
remote:        │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7
remote:        │   ├── string_decoder@0.10.31
remote:        │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
remote:        ├─┬ passport@0.3.2
remote:        │ ├── passport-strategy@1.0.0
remote:        │ └── pause@0.0.1
remote:        ├── passport-local@1.0.0
remote:        └─┬ socket.io@1.4.8
remote:        ├─┬ engine.io@1.6.11
remote:        │ ├─┬ accepts@1.1.4
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.0.14
remote:        │ │ │ └── mime-db@1.12.0
remote:        │ │ └── negotiator@0.4.9
remote:        │ ├── base64id@0.1.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ engine.io-parser@1.2.4
remote:        │ │ ├── after@0.8.1
remote:        │ │ ├── arraybuffer.slice@0.0.6
remote:        │ │ ├── base64-arraybuffer@0.1.2
remote:        │ │ ├── blob@0.0.4
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ has-binary@0.1.6
remote:        │ │ │ └── isarray@0.0.1
remote:        │ │ └── utf8@2.1.0
remote:        │ └─┬ ws@1.1.0
remote:        │   ├── options@0.0.6
remote:        │   └── ultron@1.0.2
remote:        ├─┬ has-binary@0.1.7
remote:        │ └── isarray@0.0.1
remote:        ├─┬ socket.io-adapter@0.4.0
remote:        │ └─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.2
remote:        │   ├── debug@0.7.4
remote:        │   ├── isarray@0.0.1
remote:        │   └── json3@3.2.6
remote:        ├─┬ socket.io-client@1.4.8
remote:        │ ├── backo2@1.0.2
remote:        │ ├── component-bind@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── component-emitter@1.2.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ engine.io-client@1.6.11
remote:        │ │ ├── component-inherit@0.0.3
remote:        │ │ ├── has-cors@1.1.0
remote:        │ │ ├── parsejson@0.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├── parseqs@0.0.2
remote:        │ │ ├── ws@1.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├── xmlhttprequest-ssl@1.5.1
remote:        │ │ └── yeast@0.1.2
remote:        │ ├── indexof@0.0.1
remote:        │ ├── object-component@0.0.3
remote:        │ ├─┬ parseuri@0.0.4
remote:        │ │ └─┬ better-assert@1.0.2
remote:        │ │   └── callsite@1.0.0
remote:        │ └── to-array@0.1.4
remote:        └─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.6
remote:        ├── benchmark@1.0.0
remote:        ├── component-emitter@1.1.2
remote:        ├── isarray@0.0.1
remote:        └── json3@3.3.2
```

Errors : in console :

```
at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/socket.io.js" host=HOST request_id=71077d84-55ec-4f02-b2bf-8dd79c29ac89 fwd="84.208.103.77" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=243
```

Comment: I don't see the part where you use `routes` or serve the html file to the user. Are you testing this by going to http://localhost:3000 ? It would also help to know which tutorial you're following.

Comment: I don't understand: why are you creating two HTTP servers (one in `app.js` and one in `index.js`)?

Comment: Everything is up and running except the socket.io. And I get this in the log :at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LS8vYVB"  fwd="148.122.58.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=243

Comment: @ChrisG I'm now following the socket.io tutorial, and I'm sure I have installed the socket.io package. but still in console it says that it can't find the socket.io/socket.io.js . I have uploaded the app on heroku online, the other parts are working fine, except the socket. And I can't find the reason.

Comment: Your webserver isn't set up to serve static files. I'm not even clear how you get HTML code to show up in your browser. Also, the code in your question is not the code from the tutorial. Follow the tutorial to the letter and it will work.

Comment: @ChrisG What do you mean by "Your webserver isn't set up to serve static files.". I changed the code and just followed the tutorial exactly( I haven't edited the code in this post, but I have almost copy and pasted the code from that chat tutorial to my own application )

Comment: @Maziar You didn't answer the question from my first comment yet. Are you visiting http://localhost:3000 to test the code? If so, the above code doesn't send anything back to the browser. Not socket.js, and not anything else either. Serving static files means the browser will display index.html when you go to http://localhost:3000/index.html.

Comment: Your browser is apparently sending a GET request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` but the server isn't set up to send the file, or it doesn't exist in the folder set up as document root.